# How to handle unequal sample size with multiple factors?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, methodology

The following dataset shows observations (count data) of cedar trees growing in small, medium, or large forest gaps (i.e. openings).  You can see that that there is an unequal sample size and normality is questionable.  I would like to test the following hypotheses:

- Ho: Cedar trees grow on all substrates equally among all gap sizes
- Ho: Growth on individual substrates (e.g. rock) does not differ
  between gap size classes

My initial thoughts are that ANOVA would be inappropriate due to unequal sample sizes; contingency tables may be able to handle the structure of the data, although probably cannot address the hypotheses I am interested in testing.  Goodness of fit tests seem promising.  What statistical methods would be appropriate to address these types of data and hypotheses?

Data is in the following form:

[image]

Comment: @Nick Post edited to include data.